# Disable specific days in datetimepicker Ionic + React

Tags: javascript, react-native, ionic-framework, momentjs, datetimepicker

I am developing an app using Ionic Framework and I need to disable few days e.g. Mon, Wed, Fri or Sat, Sun from the datetimepicker.

```js
 function calCulateDays(appDate: string, dayIsAvailable: (date: Date) => boolean) {

    var open = business.hours.filter(x => x.is_closed == false);
    openDays = _.pluck(open, "day");

    var a = moment(appDate).endOf('month');
    var b = moment(appDate);
    var i = moment(appDate).date();

    let arr: number[] = [];
    for (i; i <= a.date(); i++) {


      if (dayIsAvailable(b.toDate())) {
        arr.push(i);
      }

      b.add(1, "day");

    }

    setDayValues(arr);

  }
```

```
<IonDatetime placeholder="Select Date" value={appDate} onIonChange={e => onDateChange(e.detail.value)} displayFormat="YYYY-MMM-DD HH:mm"  min={dateToday} max={dateTill} dayValues={dayValues}  />
```

According to the doc we can specify dayValues to display the dates. I am able to disable the days of current month but I am not sure how to set days for each months.

Is there anyone who can guide me on this. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.